# Getting Check that 'apps.ChatbotConfig.name' is correct. after restructuring

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I changed my project's structure by adding everything in a `src` folder, but my server stopped working.

The error that I'm getting is :

> Cannot import 'chatbot'. Check that 'apps.ChatbotConfig.name' is
>   correct

I've tried to look for an answer, and most of the them suggest to change `apps.py` to `name = 'src.chatbot'`, but that didn't work for me. Tried to change the `apps.ChatbotConfig.name` but if I change anything, it says `no Module named 'chatbot'`.

Here is my structure.

[image: [project structure]

base.py

```
DJANGO_APPS = [
    "apps.ChatbotConfig",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    # "django.contrib.humanize", # Handy template tags
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "debug_toolbar",
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]
```

#### apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ChatbotConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'chatbot'
```

#### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.apps import apps

app = apps.get_app_config('chatbot')

for model_name, model in app.models.items():
    admin.site.register(model)
```

#### Full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lbajarunas\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 143, in create
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatbot'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 30, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lbajarunas\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\lbajarunas\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\lbajarunas\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\lbajarunas\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\lbajarunas\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 147, in create
    app_name, mod_path, cls_name,
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'chatbot'. Check that 'apps.ChatbotConfig.name' is correct.
```

Comment: What is the app name ?

Comment: But generally you import either like this : `<app name>.apps.<app config>`

Comment: I already solved the problem, the manage.py file was needed to be changed, the path was not correct.

Comment: Ah, Then Good Luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix my problem by changing the manage.py file. Fixed the path in main().

From:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.local")
```

To:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "projectname.config.settings.local")
```